# Why does a Zebra EMDKManager return null when asked for ProfileManager instance in MAUI project?

Tags: android, maui, zebra

In my MAUI app, I need to use the Zebra EMDK, mainly to use the Profile switching feature to get more out of Zebra devices, than is usually allowed on Android.
For this, according to Zebra docs and also multiple sample projects here and there, I first need to get a EMDKManager instance and open it. This works.

Then I should get a ProfileManager instance using code

```
public void OnOpened(EMDKManager emdkManagerInstance)
    {
        this.emdkManager = emdkManagerInstance;

        
        // Get the ProfileManager object to process the profiles
        profileManager = (ProfileManager)emdkManager.GetInstance(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.Profile);
        
        ...
       

    }
```

This is where I get stuck, because the profileManager is always null. I tried this on several Zebra devices with different Android versions with no luck.
Is the problem in using MAUI instead of Xamarin?